# HttpClient with infinite time out throws time out exception

Tags: c#, http, dotnet-httpclient

My HttpClient uses digest authentication to connect to the server and expects search queries in response. These search queries can come in any time so the client is expected to leave the connection open at all times.

The connection is made using the following code:

```
public static async void ListenForSearchQueries(int resourceId)
{
    var url = $"xxx/yyy/{resourceId}/waitForSearchRequest?token=abc";

    var httpHandler = new HttpClientHandler { PreAuthenticate = true };

    using (var digestAuthMessageHandler = new DigestAuthMessageHandler(httpHandler, "user", "password"))
    using (var client = new HttpClient(digestAuthMessageHandler))
    {
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Timeout.Infinite);

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);

        var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            tokenSource.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Timeout.Infinite));

        using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, tokenSource.Token))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nResponse code: " + response.StatusCode);

            using (var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(body))
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
         }
    }
}
```

This is how the method is being used in the Main method of a console application.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
   const int serviceId = 128;
   .
   .
   .
   ListenForSearchQueries(resourceId);
   Console.ReadKey();
}
```

This is what the output on the console window looks like:

```
Response code: OK
--searchRequestBoundary
```

Even though the timeout for the client is set to infinity, the connection times out after roughly five minutes (which is not the default timeout of the HttpClient) after the first output, throwing the following exception.

```
System.IO.IOException occurred
  HResult=0x80131620
  Message=The read operation failed, see inner exception.
  Source=System.Net.Http
  StackTrace:
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.WebExceptionWrapperStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Http.DelegatingStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer()
   at System.IO.StreamReader.get_EndOfStream()
   at ConsoleTester.Program.<ListenSearchQueriesDigestAuthMessageHandler>d__10.MoveNext() in C:\Users\xyz\ProjName\ConsoleTester\Program.cs:line 270

Inner Exception 1:
WebException: The operation has timed out.
```

The DelegateHandler used for the authentication is a a rough adaption of [this](https://bitbucket.org/toburger/digestauthmessagehandler) code (see the source section).

Why is the client timing out and how can I prevent this?

My ultimate goal is to make a call and wait indefinitely for a response. When a response does come, I don't want the connection to close because more responses might come in the future. Unfortunately, I can't change anything at the server end.

Comment: avoid using `async void`. This method should be defined with a `Task`. Also show how this method is being called.

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Nkosi The method is called in the main method of the console application like this: `ListenForSearchQueries(resourceId); Console.ReadKey();`

Comment: async void is fire and forget which may be what is causing your issue. You need to make the method return a task and call wait on the task. Update the question to show the main method.

Comment: @Nkosi if I return Task and wait it then I have to make the main method of the console async as well which is causing the build to fail. `error CS4009: 'Program.Main(string[])': an entry point cannot be marked with the 'async' modifier`

Comment: Do you have a working example of a different client talking to the server in this manner? Perhaps something that came with the server itself? I'm wondering if the time out is being caused by a dependency of the httpclient that you simply don't have control over. It could even be the operating system forcing the time out as a resource management strategy. If the timeout is happening after a predictable period of time, but still less than what you're specifying for the time out, that would certainly point to something other than logic in the httpclient that you're able to control.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Although the default value for `Stream.CanTimeout` [is false](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.cantimeout(v=vs.110).aspx), returning a stream via the `response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()` gives a stream where the CanTimeout property returns true.

The default read and write time out for this stream [is 5 minutes](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2014/01/14/tackling-timeout-issues-when-uploading-large-files-with-httpwebrequest/). That is after five minutes of inactivity, the stream will throw an exception. Much similar to the exception shown in the question.

To change this behavior, ReadTimeout and/or the WriteTimeout property of the stream can be adjusted.

Below is the modified version of the `ListenForSearchQueries` method that changes the ReadTimeout to Infinite.

```
public static async void ListenForSearchQueries(int resourceId)
{
    var url = $"xxx/yyy/{resourceId}/waitForSearchRequest?token=abc";

    var httpHandler = new HttpClientHandler { PreAuthenticate = true };

    using (var digestAuthMessageHandler = new DigestAuthMessageHandler(httpHandler, "user", "password"))
    using (var client = new HttpClient(digestAuthMessageHandler))
    {
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Timeout.Infinite);

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);

        var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            tokenSource.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Timeout.Infinite));

        using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, tokenSource.Token))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nResponse code: " + response.StatusCode);

            using (var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
            {
                body.ReadTimeout = Timeout.Infinite;

                using (var reader = new StreamReader(body))
                    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
            }
         }
    }
}
```

This fixed the exception which was actually being thrown by the stream but seemed like was being thrown by the HttpClient.

Answer (score 2):

Make the method return a `Task`

```
public static async Task ListenForSearchQueries(int resourceId) {
    //...code removed for brevity
}
```

Update the console's main method to `Wait` on the `Task` to complete.

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
   const int serviceId = 128;
   .
   .
   .
   ListenForSearchQueries(resourceId).Wait();
   Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem persists with the same exception message.

Comment: @AliZahid I am curious though. Why are you using a HttpClient to listen for queries? Again I make reference to this being an XY problem.

Comment: basically I want to make a call and wait indefinitely for a response. I also don't want to close the connection when the response comes because more responses might come in the future. I can't change anything at the server end unfortunately.

Answer (score -2):

I solved this problem in the following way:

```
var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    while (b == 1)
    { 
        var bytes = new byte[1];
        try
        {
            var bytesread = await stream.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, 1);
            if (bytesread > 0)
            {
                text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

                Console.WriteLine(text);
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter escritor = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\orden\ConSegu.txt", true))
                {
                    if (ctext == 100)
                    {
                        escritor.WriteLine(text);
                        ctext = 0;
                    }
                    escritor.Write(text);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("error");
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

in this way I get byte to byte the answer and I save it in a txt
later I read the txt and I'm erasing it again. for the moment it is the solution I found to receive the notifications sent to me by the server from the persistent HTTP connection.