# Httpclient time out handling

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient

We have option to set Httpclient timeout to infinite in api call.

What all will be problems that may arise on setting time out to infinite?

HttpClient client = new():

client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1):

Answer (score 1):

Setting the HTTP client timeout to infinite can result in a number of issues, including:

- **Hanging requests**: If the API endpoint or server is unavailable or sluggish, your application may become stuck forever waiting for a response. This might make the client look unresponsive, resulting in a negative user experience.
- **Exhaustion of resources**: If your program sends too many requests that never time out, it might drain resources such as memory and network bandwidth. This can have an effect on the overall performance of the program as well as other apps operating on the same system.
- **Security concerns**: Infinite timeouts might make your application more vulnerable to security threats like Denial of Service (DoS) attacks. Malicious actors can send massive amounts of queries to your application, causing resource exhaustion and perhaps knocking it down.

Generally, a realistic timeout setting for HTTP client requests is advised to guarantee that your application can gracefully handle slow or unresponsive endpoints.

These are issues that I can able to figure out but there can be many more issues.

Answer (score 0):

The only real drawback would be that there is no timeout. You would need to make sure stream readers and such also have a changed timeout in case they take longer than 5 minutes [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45667609/18278998)